# how to get the image path from this code

Tags: android

I have a imageview and clicking on it displays a dialog box and when clicked on each dialog item I can see a camera invoked or gallery invoked. But now after I get the image on the imageview how can I get the path of the image as an extra may be.

```
image_view = new ImageView(this);

                image_view.setId(field_id);
                image_view.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher));
                image_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        selectImage();
                    }
                });


private void selectImage() {

    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Dynamic_layout.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image1.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}


    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("image1.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 20;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);

                image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "PHOTO" + File.separator + "default";
                // f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath,
                    null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 20;
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,
                    bitmapOptions));
            Log.w("path of image in gallery", picturePath + "");
            image_view.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        }
}
}
```

Comment: Declare your `imagepath varibale` global.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882479/trying-to-get-an-image-from-gallery-or-camera-in-android/25882760#25882760

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable `String imagePath` (outside `onCreate`) so all methods can access it.

Use this variable to get your path, so it can be used in the entire class :

```
     try {
            //add this
            imagePath=  f.getAbsolutePath();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 20;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                    bitmapOptions);
```

Now you can use `imagePath` anywhere in the class.