# onActivityResult() is not called. I can't display a picture

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I'm using Intent to call camera and gallery.
I call camera or gallery, but onActivityResult() is not called.
I can take a picture and can open gallery, but I can't display the picture.
where should I fix?
please teach me.

```
    public static class SelectImageDialog extends DialogFragment{
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("please select").setPositiveButton("camera",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("gallery",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY);
                }
            });
            return builder.create();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        if(requestCode==CATEGORY){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                textCategory.setText(bundle.getString("item"));
            }
        }else if(requestCode==GALLERY){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                try{
                    InputStream is=getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    is.close();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else if(requestCode==CAMERA){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageButton.setImageBitmap(savePic(bitmap));
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap savePic(Bitmap bitmap){
        String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path+"/"+fileName);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] paths = {Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+fileName};
        String[] mimeType = {"image/png"};
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), paths, mimeType, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String s, Uri uri) {
            }
        });
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882479/trying-to-get-an-image-from-gallery-or-camera-in-android/25882760#25882760

Comment: Are you also overriding `onActivityResult` in the **activity** which hosts `SelectImageDialog`? If true, paste that code too.

Comment: sorry my reply is late.
I could solve the problem.
Good to know. thank you.

Comment: @tarofess, could you please write down how you solved it? you accepted an answer but still mentioning that you already solved it. did you solve it with the accepted answer or by some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i am calling camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("my_app", ".jpg");
fileName = tempFile.getAbsolutePath(); 
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fileName );
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri );
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: sorry my reply is late.
I could solve the problem.
Good to know. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            intent.setType("image/*");

                            Intent chooser = Intent
                                    .createChooser(
                                            intent,
                                            "Choose a Picture");
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    chooser,
                                    ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY);
```

Comment: sorry my reply is late.
I could solve the problem.
Good to know. thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can find solution from this:

```
final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery",
            "Cancel" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Select Profile Photo from");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }

            else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                Intent intent;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                    intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                }

                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "gallery.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                previewCapturedImage("temp.jpg");

            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                    setImageBitmapfromPath(getPath(selectedImage));

                } else {
                    previewCapturedImage("gallery.jpg");

                }

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private String getPath(Uri uri) {
    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {

        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                sel, new String[] { id }, null);
    } else {
        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                null, null, null);
    }
    String path = null;
    try {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        path = cursor.getString(column_index).toString();
        cursor.close();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
    return path;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setImageBitmapfromPath(String picturePath) {
    try {
        if (picturePath != null) {
            bitmap = decodeFile(new File(picturePath));
            Bitmap localBitmap1 = new RoundedTransformation(8, 0)
                    .transform(bitmap);
            ByteArrayOutputStream localByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            localBitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10,
                    localByteArrayOutputStream);
            Bitmap localBitmap2 = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            localByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
            BitmapDrawable localBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(
                    getResources(), localBitmap2);

            iv_user_photo.setBackgroundDrawable(localBitmapDrawable);
            strImagepath = picturePath;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




private void previewCapturedImage(String fName) {
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
    for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
        if (temp.getName().equals(fName)) {
            f = temp;
            break;
        }
    }
    setImageBitmapfromPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
}`
```

Comment: Welcome. You need to answer the question, or post a comment if this is not an answer, but more of a informal clue, like here. See [answer]. However posting a comment on the question will require a bit more reputation.